# jquery number count to a target number and pop display on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website : [my website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)
 i have built a **jQuery counter to count up to a target number** for the points in the team.Plz click on team tab.

problem :

1. when I load the page,the jquery point count works fine.Lets say when you go to team section and refresh the page.But when I scroll to through the various sections and reach team section,the effect doesnot show up.It looks like normal numbers.Can it be made possible,when the user scrolls to the "team" section the number count with the effect shows up.

The code for that part :

```js
(function ($) {
 $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
  options = options || {};

  return $(this).each(function () {
   // set options for current element
   var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
    from:            $(this).data('from'),
    to:              $(this).data('to'),
    speed:           $(this).data('speed'),
    refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
    decimals:        $(this).data('decimals')
   }, options);

   // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
   var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
    increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

   // references & variables that will change with each update
   var self = this,
    $self = $(this),
    loopCount = 0,
    value = settings.from,
    data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

   $self.data('countTo', data);

   // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
   if (data.interval) {
    clearInterval(data.interval);
   }
   data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

   // initialize the element with the starting value
   render(value);

   function updateTimer() {
    value += increment;
    loopCount++;

    render(value);

    if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
     settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
    }

    if (loopCount >= loops) {
     // remove the interval
     $self.removeData('countTo');
     clearInterval(data.interval);
     value = settings.to;

     if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
      settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
     }
    }
   }

   function render(value) {
    var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
    $self.html(formattedValue);
   }
  });
 };

 $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
  from: 0,               // the number the element should start at
  to: 0,                 // the number the element should end at
  speed: 1000,           // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
  refreshInterval: 100,  // how often the element should be updated
  decimals: 0,           // the number of decimal places to show
  formatter: formatter,  // handler for formatting the value before rendering
  onUpdate: null,        // callback method for every time the element is updated
  onComplete: null       // callback method for when the element finishes updating
 };

 function formatter(value, settings) {
  return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
 }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
  // custom formatting example
  $('#count-number').data('countToOptions', {
 formatter: function (value, options) {
   return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
 }
  });

  // start all the timers
  $('.timer').each(count);

  function count(options) {
 var $this = $(this);
 options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || {});
 $this.countTo(options);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #808080;
   text-align: center;
}

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */
/* Column Grids */
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */
.team-leader-box {
.col_half { width: 49%; }
.col_third { width: 32%; }
.col_fourth { width: 23.5%; }
.col_fifth { width: 18.4%; }
.col_sixth { width: 15%; }
.col_three_fourth { width: 74.5%;}
.col_twothird{ width: 66%;}
.col_half,
.col_third,
.col_twothird,
.col_fourth,
.col_three_fourth,
.col_fifth{
 position: relative;
 display:inline;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.end { margin-right: 0 !important; }
/* Column Grids End */

.wrapper { width: 980px; margin: 30px auto; position: relative;}
.counter { background-color:  #808080; padding: 10px 0; border-radius: 5px;}
.count-title { font-size: 40px; font-weight: normal;  margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; }
.count-text { font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;  margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: center; }
.fa-2x { margin: 0 auto; float: none; display: table; color: #4ad1e5; }
}

.counter.col_fourth {
  background-color: #fff ;
  border-radius: 10px;

}
```

```html
<section class="main-section team" id="team"><!--main-section team-start-->
 <div class="container">
        <h2>team</h2>
        <h6>Take a closer look into our amazing team. We won’t bite.</h6>
        <div class="team-leader-block clearfix">
            <div class="team-leader-box">
                <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-03s">
                    <div class="team-leader-shadow"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    <img src="img/team-leader-pic1.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
           <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
           <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="50" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
            <p1>click to know</p1>
          </div>
         </div>

            </div>
            <div class="team-leader-box">
                <div class="team-leader  wow fadeInDown delay-06s">
                    <div class="team-leader-shadow"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    <img src="img/team-leader-pic2.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



                <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
                  <div class="counter col_fourth">
                   <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                   <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="30" data-speed="1500"></h2>
                    <p class="count-text ">points</p>
                  </div>
                 </div>
      </div>
            <div class="team-leader-box">
                <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-09s">
                    <div class="team-leader-shadow"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    <img src="img/team-leader-pic3.jpg" alt="">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
                  <div class="counter col_fourth">
                   <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
                   <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="10" data-speed="1500"></h2>
                    <p class="count-text ">points</p>
                  </div>
                 </div>



      </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="popup" id="popup">
   <div class="popup__inner">
  <header class="popup__header">
  <a onclick="$('#popup').fadeOut()" id="popup-exit">esc</a>
  </header>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/124/124" alt="Bart Veneman" width="200" height="200" class="profile__image" /><!--

  --><section class="profile__details">
  <ul class="profile__stats">
  <li>
   <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Gold</h3>
   <div class="profile_stat__number">17</div>
  </li><!--
  --><li>
   <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Silver</h3>
   <div class="profile_stat__number">8</div>
  </li><!--
  --><li>
   <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Bronze</h3>
   <div class="profile_stat__number">21</div>
  </li>
  </ul>

  <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-name"></h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Designation: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Reporting Manager: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Email: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Date of Join: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-score"></h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Latest Week Points: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Overall Points: </h2>
  <h2 class="profile__name">Medals Rewarded:</h2>




  <ul class="social">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li><!--
  --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i></a></li><!--
  --><li class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Bangalore, IN</span></li>
  </ul>
  </section>

  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

problem 2:

I am trying to make a pop-up such that when the user clicks at the points box,where the number box is,the popup is displayed.Right now it appears at the bottom of the points box.

javascript for the popup .The html is in the above codes :

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var _this = $(this);
      var block = _this.attr('href');
      $(".tab").removeClass("active");
      _this.parent().addClass("active");
      $(".counter col_fourth").hide();
      $(block).fadeIn();
    });


    /**
     * Fade in the Popup
     */
    $('.counter col_fourth').on('click', function() {
      $('#popup').fadeIn();

    });

  }); < /script>
```

please help me if anyone out here can.

Comment: In order for this to be useful for others in the future, you might want to separate this into two questions.

Comment: Thanks for the input.I have separated the question.