# jquery number count to a target number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website : [my website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/) i have built a jQuery counter to count up to a target number for the points in the team.Plz click on team tab.

problem :

1.
when I load the page,the jquery point count works fine.Lets say when you go to team section and refresh the page.But when I scroll to through the various sections and reach team section,the effect doesnot show up.It looks like normal numbers.Can it be made possible,when the user scrolls to the "team" section the number count with the effect shows up.
The code for that part :

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    options = options || {};

    return $(this).each(function() {
      // set options for current element
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, {
        from: $(this).data('from'),
        to: $(this).data('to'),
        speed: $(this).data('speed'),
        refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
        decimals: $(this).data('decimals')
      }, options);

      // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
      var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
        increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops;

      // references & variables that will change with each update
      var self = this,
        $self = $(this),
        loopCount = 0,
        value = settings.from,
        data = $self.data('countTo') || {};

      $self.data('countTo', data);

      // if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
      if (data.interval) {
        clearInterval(data.interval);
      }
      data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);

      // initialize the element with the starting value
      render(value);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;

        render(value);

        if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
        }

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          // remove the interval
          $self.removeData('countTo');
          clearInterval(data.interval);
          value = settings.to;

          if (typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function') {
            settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
          }
        }
      }

      function render(value) {
        var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
        $self.html(formattedValue);
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0, // the number the element should start at
    to: 0, // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000, // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100, // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0, // the number of decimal places to show
    formatter: formatter, // handler for formatting the value before rendering
    onUpdate: null, // callback method for every time the element is updated
    onComplete: null // callback method for when the element finishes updating
  };

  function formatter(value, settings) {
    return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
  }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function($) {
  // custom formatting example
  $('#count-number').data('countToOptions', {
    formatter: function(value, options) {
      return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    }
  });

  // start all the timers
  $('.timer').each(count);

  function count(options) {
    var $this = $(this);
    options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || {});
    $this.countTo(options);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
}
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

/* Column Grids */

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

.team-leader-box {
  .col_half {
    width: 49%;
  }
  .col_third {
    width: 32%;
  }
  .col_fourth {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
  .col_fifth {
    width: 18.4%;
  }
  .col_sixth {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .col_three_fourth {
    width: 74.5%;
  }
  .col_twothird {
    width: 66%;
  }
  .col_half,
  .col_third,
  .col_twothird,
  .col_fourth,
  .col_three_fourth,
  .col_fifth {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .end {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
  }
  /* Column Grids End */
  .wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .counter {
    background-color: #808080;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .count-title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .count-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fa-2x {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: table;
    color: #4ad1e5;
  }
}
.counter.col_fourth {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section team" id="team">
  <!--main-section team-start-->
  <div class="container">
    <h2>team</h2>
    <h6>Take a closer look into our amazing team. We won’t bite.</h6>
    <div class="team-leader-block clearfix">
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-03s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic1.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="50" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
            <p1>click to know</p1>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader  wow fadeInDown delay-06s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic2.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="30" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="team-leader-box">
        <div class="team-leader wow fadeInDown delay-09s">
          <div class="team-leader-shadow">
            <a href="#"></a>
          </div>
          <img src="img/team-leader-pic3.jpg" alt="">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-twitter"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-pinterest"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="fa-google-plus"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
          <div class="counter col_fourth">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
            <h2 class="timer count-title" id="count-number" data-to="10" data-speed="1500"></h2>
            <p class="count-text ">points</p>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="popup" id="popup">
    <div class="popup__inner">
      <header class="popup__header">
        <a onclick="$('#popup').fadeOut()" id="popup-exit">esc</a>
      </header>
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/124/124" alt="Bart Veneman" width="200" height="200" class="profile__image" />
      <!--

  -->
      <section class="profile__details">
        <ul class="profile__stats">
          <li>
            <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Gold</h3>
            <div class="profile_stat__number">17</div>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li>
            <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Silver</h3>
            <div class="profile_stat__number">8</div>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li>
            <h3 class="profile_stat__heading">Bronze</h3>
            <div class="profile_stat__number">21</div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-name"></h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Designation: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Reporting Manager: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Email: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Date of Join: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name" id="popup-score"></h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Latest Week Points: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Overall Points: </h2>
        <h2 class="profile__name">Medals Rewarded:</h2>




        <ul class="social">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i></a>
          </li>
          <!--
  -->
          <li class="location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Bangalore, IN</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This question i have asked before,I know .[jquery number count to a target number and pop display on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575560/jquery-number-count-to-a-target-number-and-pop-display-on-click). As requested I have separated the question.

kindly help.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to find various plugins related to this

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the input. Dont need a plugin.codes working fine.I just want the numbers to roll to the target number when an user scrolls and reaches  that "Team" part in the website.

Comment: Code of your page has an orphan `<script type="text/javascript">` statement in the line #550, or absent `</script>` in #549

Comment: its irrelevant.my issue is far greater than that.I havent given the code anyway @Banzay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) plugin. It implements custom appear/disappear events which are fired when an element became visible/invisible in the browser viewport.

The following code will give you a simple animation effect using the plugin. You need to ensure that each `.timer` element has a unique `id` attribute for it to work properly.

```js
// singleRun : boolean to ensure we only animate once
var singleRun = true;
// executes when .counter container becomes visible
$(".counter").on("appear", function(data) {
  // initialise the counters
  var counters = {};
  var i = 0;
  if (singleRun){
    // track each of the counters
    $(".timer").each(function(){
      counters[this.id] = $(this).data("to");
      i++;
    });
    // animate the counters
    $.each(counters, function(key, val) {
      $({countVal: 0}).animate({countVal: val}, {
        duration: 1500,
        easing:"linear",
        step: function() {
          // update the display
          $("#" + key).text(Math.floor(this.countVal));
        }
      });
    });
    singleRun = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper wow fadeInDown delay-05s">
  <div class="counter col_fourth">
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i>
    <!-- Remember a timer requires a unique id value -->
    <h2 class="timer count-title" id="UNIQUE-ID-HERE" data-to="10"></h2>
    <p class="count-text ">points</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input.seems good.I will try to integrate and let u guys know